# Rpg game in C++ x can go below 0?

Tags: c++

I'm making a c++ rpg.

here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/cyR5bzKR

And it let's me go to -1 and then i can't go anywhere.
I can also go to 4 and then it i can't go anywhere.

Any help?

I don't want this to be over complicated.

P.S. I am using Code::Blocks I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Welcome :) If you can manage to make the question self-contained, it is a lot easier to answer. What I mean by self-contained is that we shouldn't need to follow any links. This will also prevent link-rot, a stated goal of this site to make it more valuable in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to take the next action into account when deciding whether the player should be able to move or not.

Something like this ought to work...

```
if(dir == "L" && x-1 >= xMin) {
  printf("You Went Left");
  x--;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm. Really glad i found this site :D

Answer (score 0):

You have code like:

```
if (x >= min) --x;
```

You are checking if a value is greater than or equal to another value, before decrementing it. I.e. *if it is equal, you **still** decrement*, therefore, it will be less than that value afterwards.

The solution is to only decrement if it greater than the mininum:

```
if (x > min) --x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check when you are moving right that you aren't at the right most position. Similarly when moving left you need to check that you aren't at the left most position.

But you are testing you haven't gone beyond the right/left most position (and are also checking you're on the board, which seems unnecessary).

You want something like

```
if (dir == "R" && x < xmax) ++x;
else if (dir == "L" && x > xmin) --x;
```

The other tests you do are redundant.

Answer (score -1):

```
    if(dir == "L" && x > xMin)
    {
        printf("You Went Left");
        x--;
    }
    else if(dir == "R" && x < xMax)
    {
        printf("You Went Right");
        x++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You can't go that way.");
    }
```